# Adicionar JInternalFrame em outra Classe

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

Possuo um `JInternalFrame` para edição de orçamentos, meu `JDesktopPane` esta em uma classe diferente da classe que eu chamo o `JInternalFrame`, como fazer para adicionar o `JInternalFrame` no `JDesktopPane`.

Classe Inicio

```
  public class Inicio {

    JFrame frmTeczGerenciamento;
    static JLabel txtStatusDeConexao = new JLabel();
    JDesktopPane panel = new JDesktopPane();
    public JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Inicio window = new Inicio();
                    window.frmTeczGerenciamento.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Inicio() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        frmTeczGerenciamento = new JFrame();
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().setMaximumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().setLocation(new Point(1280, 1024));
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setTitle("Vers\u00E3o 1.0.8");
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setBounds(100, 100, 1280, 900);
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);






        txtStatusDeConexao.setEnabled(true);
        txtStatusDeConexao.setText("Status de conex\u00E3o");
        toolBar.add(txtStatusDeConexao);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("                                                                                       TecZ Gerencial - TecZ Sistemas");
        lblNewLabel_2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel_2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
        toolBar.add(lblNewLabel_2);


        panel.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("List.cellNoFocusBorder"));
        panel.setBackground(new Color(176, 196, 222));
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);


        desktopPane.setBounds(209, 0, 1227, 792);
        panel.add(desktopPane);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnModulosEmDesenvolvimento = new JMenu("PCP");
        mnModulosEmDesenvolvimento.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        menuBar.add(mnModulosEmDesenvolvimento);

        JMenuItem mntmGerenciar = new JMenuItem("Gerenciar");
        mnModulosEmDesenvolvimento.add(mntmGerenciar);
        mntmGerenciar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                GerenciarOrcamentos orcamento;
                orcamento = new GerenciarOrcamentos();
                orcamento.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        mntmGerenciar.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 12));


    }



    public void editarOrcamento(){
        Inicio novo = new Inicio();
        EditarOrcamento internalFrame;
        try {
            internalFrame = new EditarOrcamento();
            internalFrame.setClosable(true);
            internalFrame.setIconifiable(true);
            novo.desktopPane.add(internalFrame); 
            System.out.println("teste");
            internalFrame.setVisible(true);  
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }


 }
```

Código da classe GerenciarOrcamentos

```
public class GerenciarOrcamentos extends JInternalFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GerenciarOrcamentos frame = new GerenciarOrcamentos();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GerenciarOrcamentos() {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Gerenciar Or\u00E7amentos");

        setMaximizable(true);

        setBounds(100, 100, 956, 637);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel filtros = new JPanel();
        filtros.setBackground(new Color(214, 217, 223));
        filtros.setBounds(47, 0, 53, 21);
        contentPane.add(filtros);
        filtros.setLayout(null);
        String data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());



        JPanel detalhes_orcamentos = new JPanel();
        detalhes_orcamentos.setLayout(null);
        detalhes_orcamentos.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("ArrowButton.background"));
        detalhes_orcamentos.setBounds(47, 275, 144, 18);
        contentPane.add(detalhes_orcamentos);

        JPanel desc_item = new JPanel();
        desc_item.setLayout(null);
        desc_item.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("ArrowButton.background"));
        desc_item.setBounds(47, 458, 127, 27);
        contentPane.add(desc_item);

        JButton btnEmitirPedido = new JButton("Chamar JInternalFrame");
        btnEmitirPedido.setBounds(160, 107, 266, 42);
        contentPane.add(btnEmitirPedido);
        btnEmitirPedido.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                //Chama o JInternalFrame
                Inicio novo = new Inicio();             
                novo.editarOrcamento();



            }
        });
        btnEmitirPedido.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);

        JLabel lblAoApertarO = new JLabel("Ao apertar o bot\u00E3o, o JInternalFrame deve ser exibido no JDesktopPane da Classe Inicio");
        lblAoApertarO.setBounds(6, 75, 491, 27);
        contentPane.add(lblAoApertarO);

    }


}
```

Código da classe EditarOrcamento

```
public class EditarOrcamento extends JInternalFrame{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    String valorTotalRec = null;
    String id = null;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    EditarOrcamento frame = new EditarOrcamento();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     * @throws ParseException 
     */
    public EditarOrcamento() throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        setTitle("Editar Or\u00E7amento - Tratermik Metais");
        setMaximizable(true);

        setBounds(100, 100, 956, 637);


        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
        separator_1.setBounds(568, 106, 372, 1);
        contentPane.add(separator_1);

        JLabel lblProduto = new JLabel("Produto");
        lblProduto.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblProduto.setBounds(100, 115, 83, 14);






    }


}
```

Observações:

- A ação é realizada perfeitamente pois no console é exibido a mensagem 'teste', aparentemente o setvisible que não está sendo aceito.
- Se eu chamar o método editarOrcamento com um botão dentro da classe Inicio, o JInternalFrame é exibido normalmente.

Comment: Por favor adicione um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel executar e testar o problema.

Comment: Ok, vou criar agora e já atualizo a pergunta.

Comment: Qual é a tela principal? Como que executa esse código?

Comment: Tem Sim, a Principal é a primeira e é um Jframe a Gerenciar Orçamentos é a segunda e também é um JFrame.
Eu preciso exibir o editar orçamento dentro da classe Principal e ele deve ser chamado na classe gerenciar orçamento.

Comment: É uma pessima pratica ter 2 jframes. Se precisa de mais tela, deve usar JDialog.

Comment: Na verdade estamos convertendo o sistema todo para JInternalFrame, ele foi feito todo com JFrame e ficou muito ruim de utilizar.

Comment: Então você deve converter essa classe gerenciarorcamento para jinternalframe, se fizer isso, fica fácil resolver o problema. Tem algum problema converter ela pra jinternalframe?

Comment: Fiz a conversão vou atualizar o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após a edição, percebi que o que você está tentando fazer é abrir um `InternalFrame` a partir de outro, e para fazer isso, basta recuperar o `JDesktopPane`. Isso é possível graças ao método `getParent()`, que recupera o container que mantem o componente atual, no seu caso, o frame interno `GerenciarOrcamentos`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GerenciarOrcamentos extends JInternalFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GerenciarOrcamentos frame = new GerenciarOrcamentos();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GerenciarOrcamentos() {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Gerenciar Or\u00E7amentos");

        setMaximizable(true);

        setBounds(100, 100, 956, 637);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel filtros = new JPanel();
        filtros.setBackground(new Color(214, 217, 223));
        filtros.setBounds(47, 0, 53, 21);
        contentPane.add(filtros);
        filtros.setLayout(null);
        String data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        JPanel detalhes_orcamentos = new JPanel();
        detalhes_orcamentos.setLayout(null);
        detalhes_orcamentos.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("ArrowButton.background"));
        detalhes_orcamentos.setBounds(47, 275, 144, 18);
        contentPane.add(detalhes_orcamentos);

        JPanel desc_item = new JPanel();
        desc_item.setLayout(null);
        desc_item.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("ArrowButton.background"));
        desc_item.setBounds(47, 458, 127, 27);
        contentPane.add(desc_item);

        JButton btnEmitirPedido = new JButton("Chamar JInternalFrame");
        btnEmitirPedido.setBounds(160, 107, 266, 42);
        contentPane.add(btnEmitirPedido);
        btnEmitirPedido.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                EditarOrcamento internalFrame;
                try {
                    internalFrame = new EditarOrcamento();
                    internalFrame.setClosable(true);
                    internalFrame.setIconifiable(true);
                    getParent().add(internalFrame);
                    System.out.println("teste");
                    internalFrame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException | ParseException ex) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnEmitirPedido.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);

        JLabel lblAoApertarO = new JLabel(
                "Ao apertar o bot\u00E3o, o JInternalFrame deve ser exibido no JDesktopPane da Classe Inicio");
        lblAoApertarO.setBounds(6, 75, 491, 27);
        contentPane.add(lblAoApertarO);

    }

}
```

O que fiz ai foi trazer o método `editarOrcamento` da classe `Inicio` para o lugar correto, que é no botao do frame interno que inicia a classe `EditarOrcamento`. Com isso, o método pode ser apagado.

Sua classe `Inicio` ficou da forma abaixo, e a classe `EditarOrcamento` não foi alterada.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Inicio {

    JFrame frmTeczGerenciamento;
    static JLabel txtStatusDeConexao = new JLabel();
    JDesktopPane panel = new JDesktopPane();
    public JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Inicio window = new Inicio();
                    window.frmTeczGerenciamento.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Inicio() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        frmTeczGerenciamento = new JFrame();
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().setMaximumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().setLocation(new Point(1280, 1024));
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setTitle("Vers\u00E3o 1.0.8");
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setBounds(100, 100, 1280, 900);
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        txtStatusDeConexao.setEnabled(true);
        txtStatusDeConexao.setText("Status de conex\u00E3o");
        toolBar.add(txtStatusDeConexao);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel(" TecZ Gerencial - TecZ Sistemas");
        lblNewLabel_2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel_2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
        toolBar.add(lblNewLabel_2);

        panel.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("List.cellNoFocusBorder"));
        panel.setBackground(new Color(176, 196, 222));
        frmTeczGerenciamento.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        desktopPane.setBounds(209, 0, 1227, 792);
        panel.add(desktopPane);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frmTeczGerenciamento.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnModulosEmDesenvolvimento = new JMenu("PCP");
        mnModulosEmDesenvolvimento.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        menuBar.add(mnModulosEmDesenvolvimento);

        JMenuItem mntmGerenciar = new JMenuItem("Gerenciar");
        mnModulosEmDesenvolvimento.add(mntmGerenciar);
        mntmGerenciar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                GerenciarOrcamentos orcamento;
                orcamento = new GerenciarOrcamentos();
                desktopPane.add(orcamento);
                orcamento.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        mntmGerenciar.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 12));
    }
}
```

Com isso, o código funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: A resposta está correta, caso tenha problema, favor informar. Negativar é facil, dificil é apontar o problema, se é que esse voto foi por esse motivo.